# Sizeof confusion when malloc-ing char* and char **

Tags: c, string

I have the following simple code to test strncpy-ing overflow:

```
int main() {

  char *test = "hellooo";

  char **str_arr;
  str_arr = malloc(sizeof(char*));
  // allocate 5 bytes
  str_arr[0] = malloc(5);

  printf("%s size is %lu\n", strncpy ( str_arr[0], test, sizeof(str_arr[0]) ), sizeof(str_arr[0]));

  free(str_arr[0]);
  free(str_arr);
}
```

It prints

```
hellooo size is 8
```

My question is why does it print "hellooo" as opposed to "hell", since I allocated only 5 bytes? How can I allocate in such a way that it prints "hell" (with null-termination)?

Comment: With five bytes, it should print "hell". You're missing a null terminator. You are also using the wrong format specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: Why did you tag C++? This could would not compile in C++ (not casting `malloc`) but also one would either use `new` in general or preferably `std::string` and `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: yes gotcha. but why does it print "hellooo" instead of "hell"?

Comment: You would need 6 bytes for null-terminated "hello". Also, `sizeof` a `char*` will not give you the length of the string, but the size of the pointer.

Comment: Using `sizeof` on a pointer always gives you the size of the pointer, and not what it points at.

Comment: Also, [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) is dangerous, because if there's no terminator in the bytes you copy, then it will ***not*** add a terminator.

Comment: so, what's the correct input argument for size_t in this case? strlen(str_arr[0])? I would like to get the number of bytes that I allocated

Comment: Regarding getting the number of bytes you allocated, that's not possible in standard C, you have to keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a buffer overflow. You allocated 5 bytes but you pushed more than 5.
`char *` is not a real string type, it is just `char` address, so you can try to access more than 5 bytes from there, and this is exactly what you did:
You wrote 8 bytes `"hellooo"` which is an array of 8 bytes (`NUL` terminated array). That overflow will commonly produce one of two results:

1. Doing so makes your application access some memory that your are unable to write in, and the application crashes;
2. Your system lets you write into a memory you are not suppose to write in (this is actually your case). That situation is worst than the previous one because there is a problem but you weren't able to detect it easily, and this could corrupt other data in the program.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(str_arr[0])` is`sizeof( char* )` i.e. size of the pointer

Also, you need 6 bytes for "hello", 1 extra for null termination

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof(str_arr[0])` is returning the size of a pointer, not the number of bytes you allocated.  `sizeof` is a compile-time construct, it has no idea how many bytes you allocated at run-time.

There is also a big flaw in `strncpy` - if the string reaches the end of the buffer, you don't get a null terminating character. You need to add it yourself after the copy.

```
strncpy(str_arr[0], test, 5);
str_arr[0][5] = 0;
```

Comment: so instead of sizeof, I should do strlen?

Comment: @Mariska you can't do `strlen` on an uninitialized buffer. You simply need to remember the number of characters you allocated. C won't remember it for you.

Comment: ok gotcha. another question is, if I malloc-ed 5 bytes, how can I copy 8 bytes to it and not get an error (per my program above)?

Comment: @Mariska no, you need to use the value `5` instead of strlen. You have allocated memory with malloc() with a value of 5, there's no way to query the allocated memory to learn that you have done so. (Ofcourse instead of hardcoding 5 that you pass to malloc, you can place 5 in a variable or a #define that you use both in malloc() and strncpy(). If you malloc 5 bytes you cannot place 8 bytes there, the only way around it is to allocate 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes I see what you're saying, but I was confused as to why the program above still runs without error, since I allocated 5 bytes and then I copied "hellooo" to it, which has 8 bytes. Shouldn't there be an overflow or something?

Comment: @Mariska Sure there's probably an overflow. Your code exhibits undefined behavior, so there's no telling what will happen. It could crash, it could appear to work, it could crash the program later on in a different place.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks Mark! Thanks to Jean too!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is correct but because:

```
char *test = "hellooo";
char **str_arr;
str_arr = malloc(sizeof(char*));
// allocate 5 bytes
str_arr[0] = malloc(5);

printf("%s size is %lu\n", strncpy ( str_arr[0], test, sizeof(str_arr[0])), sizeof(str_arr[0]));
```

is something like

```
test --> |h|e|l|l|o|o|o|\0|
          ^
          |
str_arr---
```

and

```
printf("%s size is %lu\n", strncpy ( str_arr[0], test, sizeof(str_arr[0])), sizeof(str_arr[0]));
```

will print until until `\0`, that means it will print the whole string.